# Responsive embed in Bootstrap 3 doesn't work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hello im creating a web site with Bootstrap 3, everything was going well till i tried to put a Youtube video in my site, so i used responsive embed class that Bootstrap provides but when i display the content of my website the video doesn't show it, i've tried many things like copying the code exactly of Bootstrap page but it still does not work!. Can someone help me?. This is my code:

```
<!-- PROMOTIONAL VIDEO -->
<section class="wrap" id="promo-video">
    <div class="container">

    <div class="header-section">
        <h2>Mira el video de presentacion</h2>
    </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
                <!-- 16:9 aspect ratio -->
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
            <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H0uvGe0AhNI"></iframe>
            </div>
            </div><!-- .col -->
        </div><!-- row -->

    </div><!-- .container -->
</section>
<!-- END PROMOTIONAL VIDEO -->
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your code src attr is wrong for IFRAME embed.
You need like this.

```
<iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/PIh2xe4jnpk"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 3):

**You have entered wrong input url...**

try this....

```html
<!-- 16:9 aspect ratio -->
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/PIh2xe4jnpk"></iframe>
</div>
<!-- 4:3 aspect ratio -->
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/PIh2xe4jnpk"></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you just have to change the url by your hand .. just remove that part (/watch?v=)from the url and put(/embed/)instate